# Join two .less files into one css file

Tags: css, less

When working with lesscss I would like to join two or three .less files into one **super** css file.

I know that you can do it using some little *ruby magic*, but I would like to know if there is  something simple in the less engine?

Answer (score 24):

You can use `import`, similar to how you can in a regular CSS file.

```
@import "reset";
@import "config";
@import "header";
@import "forms";
```

Taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132138/css-redundancy-when-using-less-and-its-import). It's also mentioned in the "Importing" section of the [Less Documentation](http://lesscss.org/#docs).

Comment: +1 for referencing that SO post. It's definitely worth taking a look at when using `@import`

Comment: if this is taken from that post, is this q not a dupe?

Answer (score 12):

### Simple solution:

1. Create a **main.less** file and open it (name it as you like)
2. Import your other css and less files via **`@import`**

   - `@import "filename.less";` for less files
   - `@import "filename.css";` for css files.
3. Compile your main.less file and just include this main.css in your site
4. Smile :)

Comment: This resulting css files, has import statements for each of the css files.  The css is not merged, The files remain separated.

Comment: @Mick if you use a tool like lessc (`lessc main.less main.css`) it will result only in one file