# Why can't I import .less files into a single .less file?

Tags: css, less

I have this structure of my files:

`lib/css/...` contains my styles divided into single .less files for each kind of area.

`lib/style.less` is the file I want to gather my sub-style files into - and the file I want to be linked into the HTML.

When I type in (into `style.less`):

`@import url("/css/StyleToImport.less");`

or

`@import "/css/StyleToImport.less";`

... I get a syntax error.

Is it really impossible to combine .less files into a single file?

It could be really handy to have 1 single file to contain all variables for colors, dimensions etc.

But as it is now, I have to use `<link ...>` tags in HTML to every single file - which is not so handy.

P.S. I have read [Join two .less files into one css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538605/join-two-less-files-into-one-css-file)

and I have read this:

> **Importing**
>
> Importing works pretty much
>   as expected. You can import a .less
>   file, and all the variables in it will
>   be available. If the file is a .less,
>   the extension is optional:
>
> @import "library";
>
> @import "typo.css";

Comment: can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Syntax Error on line 1

http://localhost:8080/project/lib/style.less on line 1, column 1:

    * 1 @IMPORT "./css/lib";

    * 2 @charset "utf-8";

Comment: not complete sure what the error is - i would try using lessapp and making sure your less files have at lest one style declared

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to import LESS-files into a common "main" LESS-file. That way I can refer to all my variables etc etc. But it won't work!! Am i doing something wrong with the way to link to the less.js file?

Comment: Extremely late to the party, but I was having this issue until I realized that I was using single quotes instead of double quotes- so I should have been using `@import "variables"` but instead was using `@import 'variables'`.  too much JS over the years...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I just tried this on my local environment, putting vars into `vars.less` and mixins into `conf.less`. The file structure similar to yours, with the base .less file a level below the folder containing all the 'includes'.

So I had `css` folder which had my `main.less` file and then `css/less/vars.less | conf.less`

To import both of those:

```
@import "less/vars.less";
@import "less/conf.less";
```

My only answer is to remove the first `/` in your `@import` statement. I had similar problems when trying to import a google font into my `.less` file.

Worth a shot at least, because using the same structure as yours mine is working.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem where the imports seemed to fail silently.  It turned out that my editor had saved the @import-ed files as UTF-8 with BOM, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551971/less-compile-error-parseerror-syntax-error-on-line-1).

For whatever reason, the LESS compiler chokes silently on @import-ed files that have a BOM, even though it barfs up an error if your **root** file has a BOM.

Try re-saving your @import-ed files without a BOM, and it just might work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is without the error.

I would suggest using lessapp, http://incident57.com/less/, which i have found works very well and is a little easier to use. Also be wary of trying to import blank files cause it can throw an error.

I uploaded some basic code that i use to structure my files depending on the project - you can get them at https://github.com/danethurber/seamLESS. That maybe able to help and if you or anybody wants to contribute i'ld be happy for the help :)

Comment: Let me get this seamLESS right... You link to a stand-alone .css file in the HTML file. And where exactly do you use the .less files?

Comment: the less files are in the less folder - i'm using less to compile all the other files and output a css file

Comment: Aha - it seems I can't run that less.app without a mac -.-' But I thought putting `<script src="lib/js/less.js"></script>` in the end of the `<head>` tag compiles it for me?

Comment: you can do that as well - i just prefer to compile it so the browser doesn't have to

Comment: make sure to put the less file before the js

<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/stylesheets/main.less" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>

Comment: But right now I have linked to my style.less like this `<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="lib/style.less" type="text/css" />`. And after that linked to the less.js script... It still doesn't enable me to `@import` anything...

Answer (score 1):

As you are linking to /directory it looks from root top down and in this case would not find it. So @Daniel is correct by suggesting to remove the slash.

You should link it as such:

```
@import url("css/StyleToImport.less");
```

This, because your starting point is within the css directory itself and then point down into that directory css/ and then pointing to the file itself.

If you would need to go first up a directory and then over and down you would do

```
../directory/file.less
```