# Compiling all less files into one stylesheet?

Tags: css, less

I am using simpless, I drag the project into it and target all the less files to styles.css

The issue is when compiling the less stylesheets are just over writing each other rather than being merged together. Is there a way when compiling to merge them all into styles.css ?

Comment: Answered in previous quesion. Have a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538605/join-two-less-files-into-one-css-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create a master less file that imports the subfiles. The master file would import the subfiles with:

```
@import "myfile1.less";
@import "myfile2.less";
```

Into the compiler, you just pass the master less file.

Hope this helps // ph