# Using less-middleware to compile multiple source CSS files into one?

Tags: node.js, less, middleware

In my Node.js application, I am using [less-middleware](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware) to compile the LESS files into CSS files. Works great with single files:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/public/css') }));
```

However, I was wondering if it were possible to take two source `.less` files, and compile (and optinally minify) them into one single `.css` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working using `@import`:

#### style.less

```
... LESS code...
```

#### style2.less

```
... more LESS...
```

#### combined.less

```
@import "style";
@import "style2";
```

via [Join two .less files into one css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538605/join-two-less-files-into-one-css-file)