# With Grunt, how can I compile all *.less files, if I have global mixins and constants?

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I want to organize my HTML, JS, and LESS by module.  I'm already using Grunt to compile `*.js` and `*.html` from my source folders.

So I configured grunt as follows:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
        ALL: {
             files: { 'compiled.css': '**/*.less' }
        }
    }
}
```

But this runs into a major problem: constants and mixins from my `/helper/*.less` files are not accessible to other .less files.
It seems like `grunt-contrib-less` compiles each individual .less file, and then combines the output, but doesn't compile anything "globally".

The only solution I can think of is to create and maintain a `master.less` that `@import`s each individual .less file.  But I'm trying to achieve an extremely modular build process, and I don't have to list any HTML or JS files, so I'm really hoping to find a `*.less` solution too!

Comment: Well, yes, If you want your partials to became compilable they *must* import required stuff. Things like `/**/*.less` are for compiling multiple *independed* stylesheets (and for that reason it just *can't* implicitly share anything between those files).

Comment: I updated my question with a sample config.  Long story short, `*.less` does compile to a single output file, but it seems to simply combine the results from the individual compiled files.  I'm looking for any sort of `*.less` solution, if you can think of any?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538605/join-two-less-files-into-one-css-file

Comment: @sobolevn That's what I mentioned in my last paragraph.  I was hoping that I wouldn't have to maintain a list of `@import` statements, because it'd be great for development to just go create some new files, and the build process would automatically pick them up.

Comment: [`less-plugin-glob`](https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Hey, post your comment as an answer if you want me to upvote it!  That looks like it might be the right answer!

Comment: Ah, feel free to append it to your own answer (an answer of 16 letters would be too strange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @seven-phases-max for the following answer!

### [less-plugin-glob](https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob)

Allows you to use wildcards in `@import` statements!  Works perfectly!

```
// master.less
@import "helpers/**/*.less";
@import "modules/**/*.less";
```

And all you need to add to your Grunt configuration is the `plugins` option:

```
// Gruntfile.js
grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
        'MASTER': {
            src: 'master.less',
            dest: 'master.css',
            options: {
                plugins: [ require('less-plugin-glob') ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And, don't forget, `npm install less-plugin-glob`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to achieve an effortless development experience.
However, it requires a generated file and a custom task.

### Auto-generate the `master.less` file

Create a task that generates `master.less` by writing an `@import` statement for each `*.less` file:

```
grunt.registerTask('generate-master-less', '', function() {
    generateFileList({
        srcCwd: 'modules',
        src: '**/*.less',
        dest: 'less/master.less',
        header: '// THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY grunt generate-master-less\n',
        footer: '// THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY grunt generate-master-less\n',
        template: '@import "<%= filename %>";\n',
        join: ''
    });
});

function generateFileList(options) {
    var _ = grunt.util._;
    var files = grunt.file.expand({ cwd: options.srcCwd }, options.src);

    var results = files.map(function (filename) {
        return _.template(options.template, { 'filename': filename });
    });
    var result = options.header + results.join(options.join) + options.footer;
    grunt.file.write(options.dest, result);
}
```

Then, use `grunt-contrib-less` to just build `master.less`.